# Accessing large nested JSON data set from Hive

Tags: json, apache-spark, hive, spark-streaming

We have large nested json data coming in to a kafka topic, it has close to 3000 attributes. There is a business requirement to make all the 3000 attributes available for querying on a HIVE table.

I am planning to flatten it out and write to hdfs or hive table using spark sql

Question

- Is it a feasible requirement to have a Business facing hive table with ~3000 attributes?
- How can I ensure query performance on this large table (~3000 attributes)?

Comment: Have u checked Kafka HDFS Sink Connector https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-hdfs/index.html

Comment: Why flatten? Hive and SparkSQL support nested JSON just fine. Also, don't store JSON in Hive, use ORC or Parquet if you care about performance

Comment: Is it any problem with 3K columns?

Comment: @cricket_007 could you elaborate ? I know hive supports nested json, If I do not flatten, how can I store in hive as parquet?

Comment: @leftjoin a large table which constantly gets updated which has 3000 columns is certainly a performance concern I think

Comment: You cannot update JSON based table. Only rewrite is possible. Use JSONSerDe Table(w nested structs) -> many ORC tables. Group attributes which needs to be queried together and load into many separated tables, flatten (normalize).